# syntax error python3 after updating and upgrading

Tags: kali-linux, python, python3

When I run the command
`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, everything upgrades as usual but towards the end I get the error

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyVNC/Client.py:61: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if event is "Left":
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyVNC/Client.py:63: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  elif event is "Middle":
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyVNC/Client.py:65: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  elif event is "Right":
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyVNC/Client.py:61: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if event is "Left":
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyVNC/Client.py:63: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  elif event is "Middle":
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyVNC/Client.py:65: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  elif event is "Right"
```

I have tried looking at the code but nothing comes to mind. Any idea on how to fix?

Comment: It looks like a Warning, not an Error. I guess it's not alone and there are more lines into the output.

Answer (score 0):

first of all yes it's a warning and not an error, and it's because you're probably using this library https://github.com/cair/pyVNC

and this part (*/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyVNC/Client.py:61*) is raising a warning:

```
if event is "Left":
    button_id = 1
elif event is "Middle":
    button_id = 2
elif event is "Right":
    button_id = 4
```

As said in the message they should use "==" instead of "is"
see this article for more info https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/01/21/why-does-python-3-8-syntaxwarning-for-is-literal/

One other things is why this is raise while updating your OS, probably because you don't use a virtualenv for your python scripts.
So i would suggest you to do so : https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html